# Given a word to topic distribution, how do I calculate perplexity?

Tags: text-mining, evaluation, lda, topic-modeling

I have a blackbox LDA model which outputs word to topic distribution like follows:

```
word_1 topic_b:freq_of_word_1 topic_a:freq_of_word_1 ....
word_2 topic_a:freq_of_word_2 topic_d:freq_of_word_2 ....
.
.
```

How do I proceed to calculate perplexity? Looking at Gensim LDA code I found they use variational lower bound methods, but they have access to internal topic parameters to calculate them. In my blackbox model, all I have access is to these dumps, and the initial parameters alpha and beta.

Comment: This post may be of use: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18167/how-to-calculate-perplexity-of-a-holdout-with-latent-dirichlet-allocation

Comment: saw that post, but it is somewhat vague in describing what exactly the calculation is.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as it is not really programming related (yet).